# sonarqube-gradle-plugin: Wrong base directory derived for sub-projects two levels deep

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a multi-project with the following structure:

```
:very:bestappever
:bestappever-distrib
```

The SonarQubePlugin gives

```
:sonarqube
09:35:05.139 INFO  - Load global repositories
09:35:05.252 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=114ms
09:35:05.254 INFO  - Server id: 20160428045618
09:35:05.256 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\tk09\.sonar\cache
09:35:05.265 INFO  - Install plugins
09:35:05.401 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
09:35:05.414 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://10.48.213.38:3306/sonar
09:35:06.456 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
:sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> The base directory of the module ':very:bestappever' does not exist: C:\Workarea\verybestappever\very\:very:bestappever
```

You may note, that the full path of project ':very:bestappever' is inserted at the wrong place.

This may be related to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-12 from which I've adopted the bestappever example by moving the :bestappever project to :very:bestappever. You can find this example at https://github.com/ThiporKong/sonarqube-gradle-issue.

Am I missing something? Are there any configuration options that can be used to work with deeply nested gradle multi-projects? I've tried the proposals from [Sonarqube how to configure gradle sub-projects correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851738/sonarqube-how-to-configure-gradle-sub-projects-correctly) but to no avail.

Thanks and regards,

Thipor

Comment: seems to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896336/why-is-gradle-sonar-jacoco-looking-for-dir-and-also-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem also reported on SonarQube user group. A ticket was created (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-14) and a bugfix release 2.0.1 was deployed on Gradle plugin portal.